# How to add legend for ** data.set_index ** in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I have plotted this graph but do not know how to add legend and how to change color/shape of the graph.

Does anyone know how to do?

Thank you

[Here are the codes and graphs that I have achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUl0l.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `.plot()` method, you can pass label and color (as well as a host of other things) as arguments. Color immediately uses the color you specify, but for the label to show up you also need to call `plt.legend()`.

Example:

```py
df["Some Data"].plot(color="green", label="This is some data")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: How can I change the shape of the graph? @molybdenum42